# Phonegap different config.xml

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am currently using lastest Phonegap Desktop App.When I create my new project in my root folder there is config.xml but it's not the same. Because I want to disable the dragging in the app. For an example I can't find `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />` or even `<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it manually in config.xml file or check Drag related preference in your config.xml and disable that or if you are using any jQuery framework than you can disable drag event from that.

Comment: I tried to add it manually but it doesn't work. Can you tell me the jquery code. 

Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Have a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681129/jquery-mobile-enable-scrolling-disable-page-dragging